# React+Typescript how do I use the same event to update memoized state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recursion, react-hooks, memoization

I am making a teaching-related app that fetches questions from a backend. I memoize the question fetching process in a custom useMemo hook so that the state updates caused by entering the answer doesn't fetch a new question.

I would like to have clicking the same question type multiple times in a row generate a new question of that type each time. Right now, because the memo depends on the state variable I am using to keep track of what the current question type is, clicking the same one twice will not cause a new question to be generated.

The solutions I've tried inevitably end up in infinite recursive loops. Primarily I've tried creating "dummy" variables to update the state, but then you need some condition to trigger the dummy variables to update. I need some sort of fallback condition to tell the dummy state to stop updating, but I haven't figured out how to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by handling the case inside of the onClick() of the question selection component. I pass a dummy variable as a dependency inside the Props interface of the question selector and the question fetching hook.

```
const [dummy, setDummy] = useState(0)
```

In the onClick event of the question selection button, I include a condition

```
onClick={() => {
    setNewWordQuery(newWordQuery);
    if (newWordQuery === questionType) setDummy(dummy + 1);
}
```

The dummy dependency isn't active in the useMemo hook, so I have to disable the "exhaustive-deps" eslint feature to get the typescript to compile.